# XML schema validation by using libxml2 SAX interface

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, sax, libxml2

Can the libxml2 SAX interface do schema validation against the whole XML contents? Currently, I have a completed xsd loaded into the memory. Based on my knowledge, libxml2 SAX interface is a stream-based parser which means it will not parse the XML at a time as while into the memory space. I only searched out an API called `xmlSchemaValidateStream`, does it do the work?

I used to validate XML against xsd based on the DOM-structure parser provided by libxml2, and that one works fine.

Comment: Have a look at `xmlSchemaSAXPlug`.